# Zombie reports: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsstring

I have used the following code.

MainView.h:

```
NSString *sCopySource;
NSString *sFileSource;

// retain and copy used both for test proposes
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sCopySource;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *sFileSource;
```

MainView.m:

```
// Inside the first method:
sCopySource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", path1, filename];
sFileSource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", path2, filename];

// Inside the second method:
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sCopySource toPath:sFileSource error:&err];
```

And take error in the last line of the code by zombie-enabled objects `sCopySource` and `sFileSource`:

```
message sent to deallocated instance
```

Why? The properties marked as `retain` and `copy`. How to fix this?

Thanks a lot for the help!

P.S. Please don't answer to use `ratain` and `release` methods. They're extremely inconvenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the property, but you are writing directly to the instance variable.

If you want to use the retain/release logic in the property, you need to use:

```
  self.sCopySource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", path1, filename];
  self.sFileSource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", path2, filename];
```

That way, the methods that do the copy and retain are used.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing.   Copy guarantees that the version you keep is not going to mutate.   Retain, on the other hand, keeps a reference to the original object, which might mutate if the original class was mutable.    Usually retain is sufficient and more efficient, but copy may be necessary when you're working with values that might mutate in other places in the code.